# MySQL dump from an unpartitioned, unindexed table into a partitioned, indexed table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 RDS instances (MySQL).

RDS1 - lots of data; no partitions; no indexes

RDS2 - less data; partitioned; indexed

I need a sensible way to do a daily load between the two servers. It's 49GB per day.

I have done this in Python and Apache Spark and it works, but it can be very slow.

Is there a way we can MySQL dump from an unpartitioned, unindexed table into a partitioned, indexed table (with the same column count)?

Thanks

Comment: Either you use replication (a question for the DBA site, not for SO) or use mysqldump to export and mysql cli / mysqlimport to import the data. There are plenty examples for the latter already here on SO.

Comment: Dump and restore data only, do not dump/restore the structure. If you want the process to be more fast - create your own dumper/restorer using SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE and LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: What kind of data?  Let's see the table definitions.  (There are other issue that we should discuss at the same time.)